# Como testar exports de um package?

Tags: typescript, jest

Eu tenho um arquivo `index.ts` que é responsável por exportar todas os componentes da seguinte forma:

```
export * from './components/com1'
export * from './components/com2'
export * from './components/com3'
export * from './components/com4'
```

E uma organização de pastas

```
src
|---components
    |---com1
    |---com2
    |---com3
    |---com4
index.ts
```

A minha dúvida é se é possível eu verificar se o index.ts tem a exportação de todos os componentes dentro da pasta components nele... No caso, é possível verificar se **todos** os componentes tem um export dentro do index.ts através de testes?

Comment: Você quer verificar quais membros estão sendo exportados ou os `import` _statements_ em si? Tente editar a sua pergunta para a tornar mais clara.

Comment: @LuizFelipe editei a pergunta, poderia ver se deu uma melhorada?

Comment: Olá caro Felipe, eu entendo a motivação da pergunta como uma duvida de avaliação do estado do programa, eu só não acho viavel fazer isso na pratica, forçar carregar todos componentes, penso eu que os componentes deveria ser isolados e que é para isso que existe o import, chamar só o que é preciso, fazer um over de tudo parece ser sobrecarregar o processo atual sem necessidade. Talvez eu tenha entendido errado algo, poderia explicar o objetivo?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento no caso, não seria carregar todos os componentes. O contexto é que eu estou criando um package de componentes, daí o meu index serve pra exportar os componentes, só que, em uma das versões, eu tinha esquecido de colocar o export no index e esse componente não ficou visível pra quem instalava o pacote, daí eu quero criar um teste pra, antes de fazer o publish, ele verificar se tudo tá sendo exportado no index, saca?

Comment: Dá uma olhada ver se essa resposta não te ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40703602/3021610

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seguindo a sua lógica, a unica forma possivel (acredito) seria fazendo um "depara" de todos os componentes requeridos para que a aplicação rode.

Na arquitetura:

```
 src
|---components
    |---com1
      \--> export function com1();
    |---com2
      \--> export function com4();
    |---com3
      \--> export function com4();
    |---com4
      \--> export function com4();
index.ts
```

Dentro de index se você fizer

```js
export * from './components/com1'
export * from './components/com2'
export * from './components/com3'
export * from './components/com4'

console.log(Object.keys(this));
console.log(hasAllExportFunctionExists(this));

function hasAllExportFunctionExists(objectStruct: any) {
    let exportedDeparaRequired = [
        "com1",
        "com2",
        "com3",
        "com4"
    ];
    return Object.keys(objectStruct).every(v => exportedDeparaRequired.includes(v));
}
```

Com o seu tsconfig.json desta forma:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "lib": [
        "dom",
        "es6",
        "es2017",
        "esnext.asynciterable"
      ],
      "sourceMap": true,
      "outDir": "./build",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "removeComments": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "strictNullChecks": true,
      "strictFunctionTypes": true,
      "noImplicitThis": true,
      "noUnusedLocals": false,
      "noUnusedParameters": false,
      "noImplicitReturns": true,
      "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "baseUrl": "./"
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "include": [
      "./src/**/*.ts"
    ]
  }
```

o `tsc` irá compilar para algo parecido com isso:

```js
"use strict";
function __export(m) {
    for (var p in m) if (!exports.hasOwnProperty(p)) exports[p] = m[p];
}
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
__export(require("./components/com1"));
__export(require("./components/com2"));
__export(require("./components/com3"));
__export(require("./components/com4"));
console.log(Object.keys(this));
hasAllExportFunctionExists(this);
function hasAllExportFunctionExists(objectStruct) {
    let exportedDeparaRequired = [
        "com1",
        "com2",
        "com3",
        "com4"
    ];
    return Object.keys(objectStruct).every(v => exportedDeparaRequired.includes(v));
}
```

O que irá retornar no "node index.js"

```
['com1', 'com2', 'com3', 'com4' ]
true
```